# Django-Rest-Framework Serializer validate data return None

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble getting data in validate() function of Serializer for my API. I'm using django `AbstractUser` Model

```
Django = "^3.1.3"
djangorestframework = "^3.12.2"
```

My serializers.py:

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, write_only=True)
    new_password_confirm = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, write_only=True)

    def validate_old_password(self, value):
        if not self.context['user'].check_password(value): # got data
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Old Password") 
    
    def validate_new_password(self, value):
        try:
             # validate the password and catch the exception
            validators.validate_password(password=value) # got data

         # the exception raised here is different than serializers.ValidationError
        except exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(list(e)) 
    
    def validate_new_password_confirm(self, value):
        try:
             # validate the password and catch the exception
            validators.validate_password(password=value) # got data

         # the exception raised here is different than serializers.ValidationError
        except exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(list(e)) 
    
    def validate(self, data):
        if data['new_password'] != data['new_password_confirm']: # both return None
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'message': ["Your password and confirmation password do not match."]})
        
        return data
```

views.py:

```
class change_password(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        received_json_data=request.data
        user = request.user
        serializer = ChangePasswordSerializer(data=received_json_data, context={'user': user})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(received_json_data['new_password']) # got new_password
            return JsonResponse({
                'message': 'Password changed.'
            }, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message':serializer.errors}, status=400)
```

The problem is in validate(self, data) the data currently return as `OrderedDict([('old_password', None), ('new_password', None), ('new_password_confirm', None)])` so it skipped the custom validation, but in other validation methods `validate_old_password` , `validate_new_password` and `validate_new_password_confirm` i got value normally when i print it out

I'm so confused on why this is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have to return the value in the validation methods.

Instead of this which doesn't return the value:

```py
def validate_old_password(self, value):
    if not self.context['user'].check_password(value): # got data
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Old Password")
```

you have to write this:

```py
def validate_old_password(self, value):
    if not self.context['user'].check_password(value): # got data
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Old Password")

    return value
```

This is also the reason why the `validate` method doesn't receive the data since the validation methods for the individual fields run first.

Comment: oh i see, it's weird the first 3 validations doesn't notify  error need to return like the one in validate() if missing return data. Also the docs not mentioning much ;-; https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#optional-fields. But thank you for answering, it worked ( i will accept when it allowed me to)

Comment: The field-level validation chapter is mentioned [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation).